# How does preprocessing and the search paths in c++ work?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have a clang.C file:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   return 1;
}
```

I also have these include paths, which will be passed in order to the compiler arguments:

```
/path/to/B.h
/path/to/A.h
/different/path/to/B.h  <-- duplicate file
```

When I add all 3 paths (in order) to my preprocessor statement and run it, I get this:

```
# 1 "clang.C"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "clang.C"
# 1 "/path/to/A.h" 1
# 2 "clang.C" 2
# 1 "/path/to/B.h" 1
# 3 "clang.C" 2

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   return 1;
}
```

I expect that the `/path/to/B.h` line should be `/differnt/path/to/B.h` since the pointer skips over `/path/to/B.h` and is at `/path/to/A.h`. When it needs to read `B.h`, is starts from `/path/to/A.h`, doesn't find it, then goes to the next `-I` path included, which would be `/different/path/to/B.h`. Is this how preprocessing works? If not, could someone explain it correctly?

Comment: There is no pointer. All paths are searched from the beginning for each include file.

Comment: Which C pre-processor are you asking about? Header search is implementation defined.

Comment: Also `#include "X.h"` and `#include <X.h>` are different in that `""` usually searches "locally" as well as on search paths; consider not using `""` _ever_.

Comment: @DYZ So everytime a new `#include ""` is found, it starts back from the first `-I` and searches through the list?

Comment: @eerorika I am using g++ and clang. I have the option of using either one.

Comment: Yes, each include file is searched through the complete path from the beginning.